# If an integer array is filled partially, why is the element after the last filled integer, '1'? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, input, integer, element

I took a large integer array and filled it partially. Then I tried printing it out upto the integers I inputted. But I accidentally also printed out the element after the last inputted integer. I realised my mistake only after two executions and surprisingly it was an additional '1' outputted each time. When I printed out two elements after the last inputted integer, it turned out to be '1' and a random integer. I get that the random integer might be junk values already in ram but what about '1'? That is my doubt.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int Arr[100], i, n; //declarations

  cout<<"Enter the number of array elements!"<<endl;
  cin>>n;
  cout<<"Enter the elements of the array"<<endl;
  for(i=0; i<n; ++i) //Reading in array elements
  cin>>Arr[i];

  cout<<"Elements of the array are: (including arr[n] and arr[n+1]) "<<endl; //Debugging
  for(i=0;i<n+2;i++)
  cout<<Arr[i]<<"\t";
  
  return 0;  
}
```

Here are the sample results of executions!

Sample 1

[image]

Sample 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any uninitialized cell in the array will behave the same as any uninitialized int variable:

It will hold a random garbage value or some kind of "left over" in that spot of memory from the last operation that occurred there...

Comment: But it is always '1' after last inputted integer while the one after '1' is always a garbage value.

Comment: My questions is why is it '1' always after the last inputted integer and why is it not a garbage value. Sorry if the question wasn't clear

Comment: @Humble_Snowman The fact that the program is printing '1' is a fluke. It doesn't help that all your variables and the entire array are uninitialized. When I run the program I get garbage in both past-the-end prints.

Comment: I guess it has to do with the compiler then. I think I am using gcc but I am not sure since I didn't install a compiler but rather let geany compile it for me.